# How to set auto location in PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

So i was develop some app in spring boot, i'm so confused how to used PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer setlocation automatically, here is my code

```
package com.org.tre.myth.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

@Configuration
public class ExternalPropertyConfig {

@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties")); //devpconfprop
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties")); //localconfprop
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

}

When i'm on local i need to deactivate dev location using comment

```
 @Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   //properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties")); //devpconfprop
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties")); //localconfprop
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

And before i deploy my app in dev, i need to do opposite thing by comment my local location and activate dev location

```
 @Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties")); //devpconfprop
    //properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/conf.properties")); //localconfprop
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

is there is a way it can do automatically set the location by detecting environment or some kind like that? please help me, feel free to comment
Thanks guys.

Comment: Use Profiles to do this.

Comment: Don't override the configurer and instead use Boot's built-in tools (primarily profiles, as Jens suggested, and environment variables/command-line arguments/configuration stores such as Vault).

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Boot's Profiles feature.

You can follow the steps below:

1. Create environment specific profiles:

   - `application.properties`
   - `application-dev.properties`

Spring Boot will automatically load all the properties of the application.properties and the profile specific properties you defined and set as active.

2. Save the content of your dev properties file (`/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/conf.properties`) inside `application-dev.properties`
   and the content of your local properties file (`src/main/resources/conf.properties`) inside application.properties.
3. Before deploying to Dev environment, make sure to set the dev profile as the spring active profile by adding this to the VM Options:
   `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

   This will load the properties inside your `application-dev.properties` and overrides the properties inside your application.properties.

   b. When running your your app locally, remove or do not specify active profile.

See link below for reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: can i using classpath by environment? cause my conf in dev and prod has same data, just having a diferent directory.

Comment: Yes you can create environment specific properties files in your classpath then specify which properties you are going use using vm args or env variables. You can also use external configuration files by adding this to the jvm args or env variables. For example: -Dspring.config.location=file:./myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/

Comment: Check out this link on how to externalize configuration files: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html